# Image editor SDK for android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, editor

Need to integrate a image editing component to my android application . Is there any SDK to implement this . Or can I implement it through inbuilt image editor in android through intent like this

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
editIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
editIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(editIntent, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many Image editor available on market but the best one I find is `Creative SDK` which is acquired by adope.Try this SDK

https://creativesdk.adobe.com/

Comment: can you provide me with th link to sign into fotor and  also inform to how to get the API key . I tried it once and am not getting the api key and am not able to sign in --  @Kat-hat

Comment: I have updated the above link...which is correct one..please Sign on and work accordingly

Comment: Can us say that in creative sdk the image editor guide documentation is not working its loading over here and showing not
[image editor component guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageeditor/index.html) @Kat-hat

Comment: check this link out https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html